# NetBeans - Upload on save fails, but it works with filezilla

Tags: ftp, netbeans-8, vsftpd

I created a fresh ftp user named `john` and changed the owner of my project recursively to `john:ftp-users`.

I tested the connection in NetBeans. I get `connection successfull!`.

However, If I try to upload changes, then I get this:

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,40,44,117,81).
STOR bla.sql.new
553 Could not create file.
DELE bla.sql.new
550 Delete operation failed.
```

So I tested the user on FileZilla. Result: everything works.

I also tested the user on the command line on the server:

```
ftp localhost
Trying ::1:21 ...
Connected to localhost.
220 Willkommen auf dem Entwicklungsserver
Name (localhost:root): john
331 Please specify the password.
Password:
230 Login successful.
Remote system type is UNIX.
Using binary mode to transfer files.
ftp>
```

As you can see the connection works.

Why can't I upload files on NetBeans?

---

The permission is set to 744 (directories) and 644 (files).

---

**/etc/vsftpd.conf**

```
write_enable=YES
dirmessage_enable=YES
nopriv_user=ftpsecure
ftpd_banner=Willkommen auf dem Entwicklungsserver
ls_recurse_enable=YES
local_enable=YES
anonymous_enable=NO
anon_world_readable_only=YES
syslog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
ascii_upload_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
listen=YES
#listen_ipv6=YES

ssl_enable=NO
rsa_cert_file=
dsa_cert_file=
#
# Limit passive ports to this range to assis firewalling
pasv_min_port=30000
pasv_max_port=30100
```

I tried [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/85414/124191) answer and [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/439992/124191) without success.

---

I looked up the error codes [553](http://www.serv-u.com/kb/1536/553-FTP-Reply-Code) and [550](https://www.smartlabsoftware.com/ref/http-status-codes.htm#code-550).

553 says it is not working because of the filename not being allowed. So I changed the filename to many different things and it still fails with the same error.

550 is permission denied.

---

Log File of FileZilla for successfully uploaded file:

```
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Status: Connect to 192.168.40.44:21 ...
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Status: Connection established, wait for welcome message ...
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 220 Welcome to the development server
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: AUTH TLS
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: AUTH SSL
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 530 Please login with USER and PASS.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Status: Unsecure server; he does not support FTP over TLS.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: USER john
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 331 Please specify the password.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: PASS *******************
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 230 Login successful.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: OPTS UTF8 ON
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 200 Always in UTF8 mode.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Status: Registered
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Status: Start uploading from C: \ Users \ PC983 \ asdfasdf.txt
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: CWD / srv / www / htdocs
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 250 Directory successfully changed.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: TYPE A
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 200 Switching to ASCII mode.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: PASV
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,40,44,117,80).
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: STOR asdfasdf.txt
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 150 Ok to send data.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 226 Transfer complete.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Status: file transfer successful, transfer 5 bytes in 1 second
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Status: Receive directory content for "/ srv / www / htdocs" ...
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: TYPE I
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 200 Switching to Binary mode.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: PASV
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,40,44,117,86).
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Command: LIST
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 150 Here comes the directory listing.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Answer: 226 Directory send OK.
2018-10-19 17:00:30 19616 3 Status: Completed displaying the directory contents for "/ srv / www / htdocs"
```

---

Passive Mode is turned on.

Comment: Show us log files from the other clients that actually show an upload of a file.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl I updated the question with the log from filezilla.

Comment: Well 1) in English please, 2) A real FTP protocol log file, not a message log from FileZilla GUI.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, I updated my post.

Comment: OK, and can you now post a similar log from NetBeans, showing a complete session and an upload of the same file to the same directory, as we can see in FileZilla log?

Comment: I was able to solve it by changing the upload directory to the home directory of the ftp user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve it by changing the upload directory to the home directory of the ftp user.

Setting the upload directory to `/srv/www/htdocs` solved it, even though the home directory of the ftpuser is already set to `/srv/www/htdocs`.

If I logged in via FileZilla, then I always started at `/srv/www/htdocs`, but I was also able to navigate to the root.

I don't know why I had to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In windows, **turn off the firewall and save, the again turn it on** and save. This did the trick for me. I was able to upload the files after that.
I had the following ftp settings :-

**Passive mode - On**
**Encryption - Pure FTP**
**Port - 21**
**Ignore disconnect errors - Off**

Answer (score 0):

Checking "encrypt only authentication process" in the remote connection management dialog - solved the problem for me!